# Awk script to find data in three file and perform replace operation

Tags: awk

Apologies in case causing inconvenience but it need solution for this.
Have three files.
Any other approach with regards to file concatenation or splitting, etc is appreciated

> If column1(billngtype) of file1 contains YMNC or YPBC then pick the
>   value of column2(documentnumber). Now find this documentnumber in
>   column1(Billdoc) of file2 and grep the corresponding value of
>   column2(price) in File2. Now need to find this value taken from
>   column2(price) of File2 in column1(salesdoc) of File3 and need to
>   fetch the corresponding value from column2(Refdoc) against the value
>   from Column1(salesdoc) of FIle3. If value captured from
>   column2(refdoc) of File3. Put that value in
>   column3(originadocumentnumber) of File1.

For Ex-

> if File 1,column1(billingtype) has YMNC and column2(documentnumber)
>   values is 420075416 and same is present in column1(Billdoc) of File2
>   in last row, then fetch the value from column2(price) which is
>   5049641151 agains that column1(billdoc) 420075416. Now find the value
>   taken from column2(price) of FIle2 in FIle3. We can see 5049641151 is
>   present in column1(Salesdoc) in File3. Now fetch the corresponding
>   value from column2(Refdoc) which is 6225972627. Now copy the final
>   value(6225972627) fetched in column3(originaldocumentnumber) against
>   the column2(documentnumber) 420075416

File1

```
billingtype documentnumber  originaldocumentnumber
YMNC            420075416    765467
YMNC            429842808    
YPBC            429842809    
INV             430071605    7688888
YPBC            430071609
```

File2

```
  Billdoc   price
4200754167  5049641141
429842808   5049641143
6400392213  5049641145
430071609   5049641147
429842809   5049641149
420075416   5049641151
```

File3

```
  Salesdoc  Refdoc  
5049641151  6225972627
5049641143  6225973664
5049641147  6225973574
5049641145  6225973553
5049641149  6225973639
5049641141  6225973652
```

Expected Output File1

```
billingtype documentnumber  originaldocumentnumber
YMNC            420075416    6225972627
YMNC            429842808    6225973664
YPBC            429842809    6225973639
INV             430071605   
YPBC            430071609    6225973574
```

Comment: Show your current approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this *simple* flow:

```
awk 'FILENAME=="file2"{bd[$1]=$2;next}
     FILENAME=="file3"{sd[$1]=$2;next}
     FNR>1{$3=sd[bd[$2]]}1' OFS="\t" file2 file3 file1
```

**Results**

```
billingtype documentnumber  originaldocumentnumber
YMNC    420075416       6225972627
YMNC    429842808       6225973664
YPBC    429842809       6225973639
INV     430071605
YPBC    430071609       6225973574
```

**Explanation**

---

**file2 and file3**

`FILENAME=="file2"{bd[$1]=$2;next}FILENAME=="file3"{sd[$1]=$2;next}`: Creates two *hashes* where the first value (key), points the second one (ruled by file name). Now `bd` contains *BillingDoc* (file1) info and `sd` *SallesDoc* (file2) data.

---

**file1**

`FNR>1`: Skips the first line of `file1` to avoid header manipulation.

`bd[$2]`: Points to the *Billing Doc* hash where the key is equal to the source file (file1) **second column**, this will give us it's price value.

So `sd[bd[$2]]` will return the *refdoc* associated with that price.

`$3=sd[bd[$2]]`: To assign the result to the third field of our expected output.

---

**Visualization**

The `1` at the end is just a *shortcut* to avoid using the print statement.

In `awk` when a condition gets matched the default action is to print the input line.

```
$ echo "test" |awk '1'
```

Is equivalent to:

```
echo "test"|awk '1==1'

echo "test"|awk '{if (1==1){print}}'
```

That's because 1 will be always true

**Last step** set de **O**utput **F**ield **S**eparator to *TAB* `OFS="\t"` to get our expected result.

Comment: @Klashxx..Thank you very much..
will let you know in case got some other issue :)

Comment: Hi @Klashxx..in your solution, we are not considering the first statement..If column1(billngtype) of file1 contains YMNC or YPBC..Can you please let me know where we can include this